# Numpy is not swapping elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to swap two indices in the 2D array of NumPy. Unfortunately, only one element is getting swapped. Here is the code:

```py
n = len(A)
perMatrix = np.zeros((n,n))
np.fill_diagonal(perMatrix, 1)
perMatrix = A

# swapping the row
print(perMatrix)
temp = perMatrix[switchIndex1]
print(temp)
# perMatrix[switchIndex1][0] = 14
perMatrix[switchIndex1], perMatrix[switchIndex2] = perMatrix[switchIndex2], perMatrix[switchIndex1]
print(perMatrix)
```

Here's what the code is outputting:

[image: Output image]

Comment: The variables `A` and `switchIndex[1|2]` are not defined. Are you trying to transpose the array? Numpy arrays have a method specifically for transposition.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add (on the line after perMatrix is created):

```
sigma = [switchIndex1, switchIndex2]
tau   = [switchIndex2, switchIndex1]
perMatrix[sigma,:] = perMatrix[tau,:]
```